# How can I refer to Saved Queries in Access VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to check records in a saved query to determine whether VBA should disable certain form controls:

```
Dim SavedQry
SavedQry = Queries!qryCurrentItems 'or Queries("qryCurrentItems")
```

Won't compile because it wants me to define the variable "Queries."

You can do this sort of thing with `Forms!FormName!ControlName` to refer to the data in a control, so why not like this?

---

For clarity; the query in question has "parameters" filled by a form. The code is below.

```
SELECT tblColour.Colour AS Colour
FROM tblColour 
INNER JOIN (tblGenCol 
INNER JOIN tblAutCol ON tblAutCol.Colour = tblGenCol.Colour) 
ON tblGenCol.Colour = tblColour.ID
WHERE tblGenCol.Genre = Forms!frmColourChoice!cmbGenre
AND tblAutCol.Author = Forms!frmColourChoice!cmbAuthor;
```

The parameters are Forms!frmColourChoice!cmbGenre and Forms!frmColourChoice!cmbAuthor.

Comment: Declare your variable `As QueryDef` and use `CurrentDb().QueryDefs("QueryName")` to set a reference to the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an object or two:

```
Dim SavedQry As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set SavedQry = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryCurrentItems")
SavedQry.Parameter("ParameterName1").Value = SomeValue
SavedQry.Parameter("ParameterName2").Value = AnotherValue
Set rs = SavedQry.OpenRecordset()
' Investigate records.
```

Comment: This gives me "Error number 3061 - Too few parameters. Expected 2." at the point `Set rs = SavedQry.OpenRecordset()`

Comment: Then set the parameter values. See edited answer, please.

Comment: But the parameters are defined in the query as coming from the open form that fires this code... Shouldn't it be able to work it out through that?

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!